# Manifest does not contain a suitable icon

Tags: arrays, json, icons, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I am using the code mention below for the icon of the web app

```
    {
      "src":"image/logo.png",
      "sizes":"512x512",
      "type":"image/png",
      "purpose":"any"
    }
  ]
```

but in chrome I am getting the error:

> Manifest does not contain a suitable icon.....

Why is it happening and how can I solve it..?

Hope for help soon.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least one PNG file of 144x144. But honestly you need a about 100 to satisfy all the possible use cases.

That is one reason why I create [PWA Starter](https://pwastarter.love2dev.com/). It generates your manifest file, icons, starter service worker and has some resources too.

You might have an image that has some corrupt bits or it might now have the right Content-Type header being served, etc.